# why do you have to translate before rotating to rotate an element around himself in canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I just started studying about HTML5  element and while trying to figure out how to rotate an element around himself I stumbled across a post saying that you have to translate the origin before rotating the element, and i was wondering why is that? isn't translating just moves the origin from which you draw things to another point in the canvas?

Answer (score 0):

You're not rotating the element, but the whole canvas. The canvas point of origin is in it's *left-top* corner. Translating to (-or actually, the oposite negative direction) your element first, would virtually translate the point of origin.